# How to share same configuration files across projects using gitlab ci/cd

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, configuration-files

I have some common configurations files that are the same for many projets. It's very painful to manage because they are just duplicate and when I have a modification for one file I need to do it for all of them.

I want to find a solution with **gitlab ci/cd to share common configuration files across different projects**.

I saw in the Gitlab documentation that you can include other gitlab files here / cd [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html). But I don't want to share only the yaml configuration file, I want to share all the configuration files that are the same in my projects.

I found an idea but I don't know if it's a good one.

Imagine a project named "A" and a project named "Common Configurations Files".

The "Common Configurations Files" project will contain all the common configurations files in a "config" folder and a gitlab ci/cd file with a function that can copy the files to the root folder.

Project A will [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html) files and will call the before_script step to copy the files to the root folder.

I don't know if it can work and I don't know how to do it.

I saw **two other options** but I don't know if it's suitable:

1. [Gitlab artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063601/gitlab-runners-artifacts-subfolders-and-files-without-parent-folder-in-zip)
2. [git submodule](https://git.trustpair.fr/data/general/-/issues/46)

Answer (score 1):

Both options, either working with a submodule or artifacts, should work for your case. Using submodules would add a little bit more complexity as you would need to keep the submodules updated in all your dependent repositories.

Another option that would be suitable here would be the use of [Gitlab Generic Packages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/). If you have a Repository that includes all your configuration files, I would suggest creating a pipeline for this repository which versions/tags the repo upon changes. After versioning, I would zip the content up and push it to this projects package repository.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
     --upload-file path/to/file.txt \
     "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/24/packages/generic/my_package/0.0.1/dependencies.zip"
```

In all your dependent projects, in the before_script you could just download and extract the zip file.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
     "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/24/packages/generic/my_package/0.0.1/dependencies.zip"
```

The example in the docs looks like this and might help you get started.

```
image: curlimages/curl:latest

stages:
  - upload
  - download

upload:
  stage: upload
  script:
    - 'curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" --upload-file path/to/file.txt "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/generic/my_package/0.0.1/file.txt"'

download:
  stage: download
  script:
    - 'wget --header="JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/generic/my_package/0.0.1/file.txt'
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you